# Is there an easy way to show these curves on the complex plane are the same?

Tags: complex-numbers

Using complex conjugates, one can show in a painfully long way that

$$|4z - 7| = 1 \iff \Re \left( \frac 1 {2-z} \right) = 2$$

Is there some way to show that this holds without using complex conjugates?

---

I have just tried something different. We want
$$i\lambda = \frac {2z-3} {z-2}$$
to be pure imaginary. Then, up to a multiplicative constant $\mu$, we have
$$
\newcommand \mat [1] {\begin{bmatrix} #1 \end{bmatrix}}
\mat {i\lambda \\ 1} = \mu \mat {2 & -3 \\ 1 & -2} \mat {z \\ 1}
$$
Inverting this system, we have
$$
-\mu \mat {z \\ 1}
    = -\mat {2 & -3 \\ 1 & -2}^{-1} \mat {i\lambda \\ 1}
    = \mat {-2 & 3 \\ -1 & 2} \mat {i\lambda \\ 1}
    = \mat {3 - 2i\lambda \\ 2 - i\lambda}
$$
Hence $\lambda$ is the parameter of the curve
$$z = \frac {3 - 2i\lambda} {2 - i\lambda}$$
And I think I should be able to take it off from here. Wish me luck!

Comment: What have you tried? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: @Saad: What have I tried? The painful long way
$$4 = \Re \left( \frac 2 {2-z} \right) = \frac 1 {2-z} + \frac 1 {2 - \bar z}$$
then multiplying times the least common denominator, then completing the modulus squared until I get $|4z -7| = 1$. I am not asking if this problem can be solved. I am asking if this problem can be solved in an easy way. Maybe there is some nice geometric insight that would spare me these horrible calculations.

Comment: Have you learned about Möbius transformations yet?

Comment: @saulspatz: Yes, but I had to embarrass myself first here, before deciding to use them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I did it.  I'm not sure if it's the same way you have in mind or not.  For simplicity, write $w=2-z$ so we want to show that $|1-4w|=1$ is the same as $\Re\left(\frac1w\right)=2$.  The curve $|1-4w|=1$ is the circle of radius $\frac14$ about $w=\frac14$.  Three points on the curve are $0,\ \frac12,$ and $\frac{1+i}4$.  The transformation $w\mapsto\frac1w$ carries these points to $\infty,$ $2,$ and $2-2i$, and we are done.

Comment: Suppose I didn't know that $\Re \left( \frac 1 {2-z} \right) = 0$ would turn out to be the circle $|4z - 7| = 1$. From general considerations, I know that the curve has to be a circle (including the case where lines on the complex plane are circles on the Riemann sphere). But is there some way to guess what specific circle it will turn out to be?

Comment: @pyon Yes, I'm sure you can, but I'm getting too sleepy to be coherent.  Pick $3$ points on the line $\Re(z)=z$ and look at their inverse images under $z\mapsto \frac1{2-z}$  I hope I said that right.

Comment: Thanks and good night, then!